# How to save all Slim Request, Response and Errors in mysql database table with log

Tags: php, mysql, logging, slim

How can I save all loges including Request, Response and PHP Errors in mysql database table ?

Comment: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog

Answer (score 0):

You can use slim hooks to trigger certain behaviors during the request lifecycle. Try

```
$app->hook('slim.after.router', function () use ($app) {
    $request = $app->request;
    $response = $app->response;

    echo '<br>Request path: ' . $request->getPathInfo();
    echo '<br>Response status: ' . $response->getStatus();
});
```

To get started.

As Mika Tuupola said, you'd be better off using a logging library, among which Monolog is great. Using Monolog with one of its database handlers would let you use `$app->log->debug` method to persist request and response objects to a DB.